# How to Count total number of attachments in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I was actually going through the below code for counting the attachments from selected emails.

```
    Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectedEmails()
    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim AttCount As Long
    Dim strMsg As String

    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For Each oMail In olSel
        'To confirm if the selected items are all emails
        If oMail.Class <> olMail Then
           strMsg = "Please select mail items only!"
           nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
           Exit Sub
        End If
        'Get the total number of the attachments in selected emails
        AttCount = oMail.Attachments.Count + AttCount
    Next

    strMsg = "There are " & AttCount & " attachments in the " & olSel.Count & " selected emails."
    nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Attachments")
End Sub
```

But this is actually considering the logo in signature and any embedded or inserted pictures in email body and showing the wrong result.

So, here I need help on below two questions:

1. Is there any way to skip them ?
2. Is there any code for counting the total documents in a zip or rar file attachment in the email ?

If there is any code, can we include that here ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but one method would be to loop on all attachments and check if their filename ends with `.zip` or `.rar`

```
  Option Explicit

  Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectedEmails()
    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim AttCount As Long
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim nRes As Long
    Dim objAttach As Outlook.Attachment

    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For Each oMail In olSel
        'To confirm if the selected items are all emails
        If oMail.Class <> olMail Then
           strMsg = "Please select mail items only!"
           nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
           Exit Sub
        End If

        'Loop on attachements
        For Each objAttach In Item.Attachments
            'increment counter if the attachement extention is .zip or .rar
            If LCase(Right(objAttach.FileName, 4)) = ".rar" Or LCase(Right(objAttach.FileName, 4)) = ".zip" Then
                AttCount = AttCount + 1
            End If
        Next objAttach 

    Next

    strMsg = "There are " & AttCount & " attachments in the " & olSel.Count & " selected emails."
    nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Attachments")
End Sub
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to count the files **within** a ZIP or RAR archive (in addition to non-archive files). I'm pretty sure to do that, you'd need to actually open the archive and process it.

Comment: Ok my bad. Yep then it would require using a specic DLLs to manipulate archives.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the things you want to do are a bit tricky.

I don't know if there's a predictable way to determine if a given attachment is a logo or embedded image. There might be, but some quick testing shows that Outlook reports the `AttachmentType` of the attachment as `olByValue` (`1`) regardless if it's a signature, logo, PDF or whatever. You might have luck by "black-listing" specific file-names or attachments, if you identify that all the logo attachments have similar names (e.g., in your count, skip files that are named `image001.jpg`. Alternatively, you could white-list specific attachments and only show attachments that are Excel, Word, or PDF files, for example.

Regarding ZIP/RAR archives: It seems that VBA doesn't have native support for opening ZIP archives. However, it appears that you can make calls to the shell for processing them.  You might want to start searching for something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?ei=l_E0W8XwFISqsgW2x4foCA&q=vba%20count%20files%20in%20ZIP&oq=vba%20count%20files%20in%20ZIP&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.116674.118927.0.119212.18.17.0.0.0.0.205.2152.0j11j3.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.14.2150...0j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20i263k1.0.MK8zj5kbpd4).